# How do I use Redux-form to get values from checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

How do you change the default boolean value for a checkbox in redux form to be the value you specify on the input itself?

For example, I have an input like this:

`<input type="checkbox" value="Pages missing or out of order" {...issue1} />`

When Redux form picks this up, it just gives me a true/false, even though I want the value "Pages missing or out of order"

Can I do something like this to get where I need to go so that when the form submits, it will submit the value "Pages missing or out of order, instead of true/false?

`<input type="checkbox" onChange={value => console.log(value.target.value)} value="Pages missing or out of order" />`

when I remove the {...issue1}, my custom onChange event handler will be called, but when I keep {...issue1}, it's completely ignored.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `redux-form` treats checkboxes as boolean values. You'll have to map the boolean to the string elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up having to step outside redux-form in order to get the checkboxes to do what I wanted, including writing custom validation, etc.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use **both** the **format** property to map from string to boolean and the **normalize** property to map from boolean to string.

*For Example,*

If you have data saved in redux state that needs to be the strings `'1'` or `'0'`, you need to use a `<Field />` like below to map to the `true` and `false` default values of the **redux-form** checkbox

```
<Field
  name='myCheckbox'
  type='checkbox
  format={v => v === '1'} // converts redux state string to boolean
  normalize={v => v ? '1' : '0'} // converts checkbox boolean to string
/>
```

Using both format and normalize you keep your checkbox `true` and `false` mapped to `'1'` and `'0'` in your redux store.