# Reactjs redux-form fields - custom checkbox/radiobox component - bug in initial checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a custom radiobutton/checkbox component -- based off the renderField. The component appears to render fine, but when I've added a "checked" parameter to this it breaks. The field is selected correctly - but when toggling options it looks like it tries to force check the old item.

//renderField

[image]

```
import React from 'react'

const renderField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, warning}}) => (
  <div className='field'>
    <label>
      {touched &&
        <span>
          {label}
        </span>
      }
      {touched &&
        ((
          error &&
            <span className="error">
              : {error}
            </span>) ||
          (
          warning &&
            <span className="warning">
              : {warning}
            </span>
        ))}
    </label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    </div>
  </div>
)

export default renderField
```

here is the new field -- the markup is different to the standard input fields.

//renderRadioCheckField

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import _ from 'underscore';

function renderRadioCheckField({input, label, type, checked, meta: {touched, error, warning}}) {
  const randId = _.uniqueId('radiocheck_');

  return (
    <div className='field'>
      <div>
        <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} id={randId} checked={checked} />
        <label className="group-label" htmlFor={randId}>
          {label}
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default renderRadioCheckField
```

--

on my form component I am importing these in and calling them as such

```
  <Field name="test" type="text" component={renderField}  label="test" />

  <br/><br/>  
  <Field name="radio-group1" type="radio" component={renderRadioCheckField} value="check1" label="Apple2" />
  <Field name="radio-group1" type="radio" component={renderRadioCheckField} value="check2" label="Peach2" checked="true" />
  <Field name="radio-group1" type="radio" component={renderRadioCheckField} value="check3" label="Orange2" />

  <br/><br/>  
  <Field name="check-group1" type="checkbox" component={renderRadioCheckField} value="check1" label="Yes" />
  <Field name="check-group1" type="checkbox" component={renderRadioCheckField} value="check2" label="No" checked="true" />
```

Comment: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.6/docs/api/Field.md/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836060/multiple-checkbox-in-redux-form

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954863/how-do-i-use-redux-form-to-get-values-from-checkboxes

Comment: - I also noticed that if I have multiple checkboxes with the same name - clicking one will check the others too.

Comment: I could replicate a strange issue where it would take two clicks to change from the one radio button to another. This just happened the first time. Later  switches worked.  Tried a few things but found no fix. Sorry

Comment: @jonahe - I tried switching it back to a const -- here is a code dump -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/144/

Comment: some basics - https://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/html/form-checkbox.php

Comment: Perhaps you can find something in this thread: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/124

Comment: -- even with a basic checkbox - preselecting it - seems to bust inside this form

Comment: -- I think you are right @jonahe -- I think the way this is to be handled is through initializing the state -- I will need this for the edit page. http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/initializeFromState/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `checked="true"`. Instead do following in your `componentDidMount()` method of React Redux Form component.

```
componentDidMount(){
        const {radio-group1} = this.props;

        //Sets initial default checked value
        this.props.change('radio-group1','check2'); 
}
```

You can do same for checkboxes.